# Isabelle: Predecessor function

Tags: isabelle

I am not sure, but I think sometimes my proofs would be easier if I had a predecessor function, e.g., in case a variable is known not to be zero.

I don't know a good example, but perhaps here: `{ fix n have "(n::nat) > 0 ⟹ (∑i<n.  f i) = Predecessor n" sorry }`

Possibly because it is not a good idea, there is no predecessor function in the library.

Is there a way to simulate a predecessor function or similar?

I have thought of this example:

```
theorem dummy:
shows "1=1" (* dummy *)
proof-

  (* Predecessor function *)
  def pred == "λnum::nat. (∑i∈{ i . Suc i = num}. i)"

  {fix n :: nat
  from pred_def have "n>0 ⟹ Suc (pred n) = n" 
  apply(induct n)
  by simp_all
  }
  show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is unnecessarily complicated. Why do you not just write

```
def pred ≡ "λn::nat. n - 1"
```

Then you can have

```
have [simp]: "⋀n. n > 0 ⟹ Suc (pred n) = n" by (simp add: pred_def)
```

In the case of `0`, the `pred` function then simply returns `0` and `Suc (pred 0) = 0` obviously doesn't hold. You could also define `pred ≡ "λn. THE n'. Suc n' = n"`. That would return the unique natural number whose successor is `n` if such a number exists (i.e. if `n > 0`) and `undefined` (i.e. some natural number you know nothing about) otherwise. However, I would argue that in this case, it is much easier and sensible to just do `pred ≡ λn::nat. n - 1`.

I would suspect that in most cases, you can simply forgo the `pred` function and write `n - 1`; however, I do know that it is sometimes good to have the `- 1` “protected” by a definition. In these cases, I usually `def` a variable `n'` as `n - 1` and prove `Suc n' = n` – basically the same thing. In my opinion, seeing as proving this takes only one line, it does not really merit a definition of its own, such as this `pred` function, but one could make a reasonable case for it, I guess.

Another thing: I've noticed you use `lemma "1 = 1"` as some kind of dummy environment to do Isar proofs in. I would like to point out the existence of `notepad`, which exists precisely for that use case and that can be used as follows:

```
notepad
begin
  have "some fact" by something
end
```

Comment: I tought (n - 1) changes the type, e.g., to int. I vaguely remeber an error message that "-" or "-1" is not defined for nat. But it seems I just wrote "n-1", but "n - 1" is correct (with a space before and after "-"). Okay, this explains a lot!

Comment: `n-1` is problematic because Isabelle parses this as `n -1`, where `-1` is the integer “negative one”. It has to be written `n - 1`. For Variables, you don't have that problem, `n-m` is fine.